# ZF2 form with optional composedObject - validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework2, annotations

## Background

I'm using **ZendFramework 2.4.0**. For sake of an example, let's assume I have two business entities in my app: **UserEntity** and **CourseEntity**. Again, for simplicity, let's say there is 1:1 relation between them. Below are simplified definition of both (getters, setters, hydration methods, namespaces, uses of classes are left out for clarity).

```
<?php
class UserEntity {
    private $name;

    private $course;
}
```

---

```
<?php
class CourseEntity {
    private $name;

    private $difficulty;
}
```

I have two forms: add user form, add course form. I'd like to use **AnnotationBuilder** with annotations in entities for clarity. I want to be able to add UserEntity with a course assigned, of course input is subject to validation. Course can also be missing. I should be able to POST to "user creation form" below payload:

```
{  
   "name":"Joe Doe",
   "course":{  // this object is optional
      "name":"Beginner guide to coding",
      "difficulty":5
   }
}
```

To achieve this, I add inline annotations to my Entity objects, which now look like:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Annotation\Name("user")
 * @Annotation\Instance("UserEntity")
 */
class UserEntity {
    /**
     * @Annotation\Required(true)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Annotation\Required(false)
     * @Annotation\AllowEmpty()
     * @Annotation\ComposedObject("CourseEntity")
     */
    private $course;
}
```

---

```
<?php
/**
 * @Annotation\Name("course")
 * @Annotation\Instance("CourseEntity")
 */
class CourseEntity {
    /**
     * @Annotation\Required(true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Annotation\Required(false)
     */
    private $difficulty;
}
```

My form looks like this:

```
<?php
$payload = json_decode($data); // payload like the one above
$form = (new AnnotationBuilder())->createForm('UserEntity');
$form->setData($payload);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    echo 'Valid !';
} else {
    var_dump(Json::encode($form->getMessages()));
}
```

## Problem

I cannot get course object to be validated correctly. There are three possibilities:

1. User entity is valid, course is present and valid - CORRECT BEHAVIOUR
2. User entity is valid, course is present and invalid - CORRECT BEHAVIOUR - validation error
3. User entity is valid, course is absent - FORM TRIES TO VALIDATE CourseEntity.

Scenario #3 is problematic. I'd expect **CourseEntity** not to get validated because of usage of **Required(false)** and **AllowEmpty()** with **ComposedObject** annotation.

When debugging the form built, it seems that required and allowEmpty options are not taken into account. Am I doing sth wrong here?

## Additional consideration

Funnily enough, when I switch the order of annotations on **UserEntity.course** field to

```
/**
 * @Annotation\ComposedObject("CourseEntity")
 * @Annotation\Required(false)
 * @Annotation\AllowEmpty()
 */
private $course;
```

then AnnotationBuilder fails to build the form with the exception:

```
Zend\InputFilter\Factory::createInput expects an array or Traversable; received "boolean"
```